# For each key/value pair in a dictionary, check if the value is of type pyspark Dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe and a list of dictionary as below -

```
    x=spark.createDataFrame(["10","11","13"], "string").toDF("age")
    results = [
         {'type': 'check_datatype',
          'kwargs': {'table': x, 'columns': ['car_id','index'], 'd_type': 'str'},
          'datasource_path': '/cars_dataset_ok/',
          'Result': False},
        {'type': 'check_string_consistency',
          'kwargs': {'table': 'cars', 'columns': x, 'string_length': 6},
          'datasource_path': '/cars_dataset_ok/',
          'Result': False}
        ]
```

I want to achieve two things -

```
1.
For each key/value pair in kwargs key, check if any value for all keys is of type pyspark Dataframe. If so, replace the value by the string "invalid dataframe"

2. For each key/value pair in kwargs key, check if value in 'table' key is of type pyspark Dataframe. If so, replace the value by the string "invalid dataframe"
```

Expected Output -

1. replace dataframe values for all key

finalresult1 =

```
[
             {'type': 'check_datatype',
              'kwargs': {'table': "invalid dataframe", 'columns': ['car_id','index'], 'd_type': 'str'},
              'datasource_path': '/cars_dataset_ok/',
              'Result': False},
            {'type': 'check_string_consistency',
              'kwargs': {'table': 'cars', 'columns': "invalid dataframe", 'string_length': 6},
              'datasource_path': '/cars_dataset_ok/',
              'Result': False}
            ]
```

2. replace dataframe wherever key in kwargs is 'table'

finalresult2=

```
    [
             {'type': 'check_datatype',
              'kwargs': {'table': "invalid dataframe", 'columns': ['car_id','index'], 'd_type': 'str'},
              'datasource_path': '/cars_dataset_ok/',
              'Result': False},
            {'type': 'check_string_consistency',
              'kwargs': {'table': 'cars', 'columns': x, 'string_length': 6},
              'datasource_path': '/cars_dataset_ok/',
              'Result': False}
            ]
```

Comment: @mck i have created a pyspark dataframe 'x' for your understanding.

Comment: any example of expected output?

Comment: output will be same list of dictionaries only but dataframe x will be replaced by the string value "invalid dataframe"

Comment: @mck I have added the expected output in 2 scenarios

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use some list/dict comprehension:

```
from pyspark.sql import DataFrame

result1 = [
    {
        k: v 
        if k != 'kwargs' 
        else {
            k2: "invalid dataframe" 
            if isinstance(v2, DataFrame) 
            else v2 
            for (k2, v2) in v.items()
        } 
        for (k, v) in d.items()
    } for d in results
]

print(result1)
# [{'type': 'check_datatype', 'kwargs': {'table': 'invalid dataframe', 'columns': ['car_id', 'index'], 'd_type': 'str'}, 'datasource_path': '/cars_dataset_ok/', 'Result': False}, {'type': 'check_string_consistency', 'kwargs': {'table': 'cars', 'columns': 'invalid dataframe', 'string_length': 6}, 'datasource_path': '/cars_dataset_ok/', 'Result': False}]

result2 = [
    {
        k: v 
        if k != 'kwargs' 
        else {
            k2: "invalid dataframe" 
            if k2 == 'table' and isinstance(v2, DataFrame) 
            else v2 
            for (k2, v2) in v.items()
        } 
        for (k, v) in d.items()
    } 
    for d in results
]

print(result2)
# [{'type': 'check_datatype', 'kwargs': {'table': 'invalid dataframe', 'columns': ['car_id', 'index'], 'd_type': 'str'}, 'datasource_path': '/cars_dataset_ok/', 'Result': False}, {'type': 'check_string_consistency', 'kwargs': {'table': 'cars', 'columns': DataFrame[age: string], 'string_length': 6}, 'datasource_path': '/cars_dataset_ok/', 'Result': False}]
```

Note that `x` will show up as `DataFrame[age: string]` when it is printed. It should still be the original dataframe.

Comment: Nested comprehensions in cases like these almost makes the code unreadable, especially when you come back to your code months later.

Comment: Having indentations will make comprehensions easier to read. Please check my edited answer.

Comment: DataFrame[age: string] is coming in print statement still. Why is it not gettig replaced with string value?

Comment: could you clarify? could you see that in my print statement, some dataframe is replaced by `invalid dataframe` at the desired positions?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `isinstance(variable,class)` to check whether a variable belongs to a certain type. The PySpark [docs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.1/api/python/) says that the DataFrames belong to the class `pyspark.sql.DataFrame`

So all we need to do is loop over and check using `isinstance`

for case 1
first create a deep copy of the new dictionary

```
import copy

finalresult1 = copy.deepcopy(result)
for dic in finalresult1:
    for k,v in dic:
        if (isinstance(v,pyspark.sql.DataFrame)):
            dic[k] = "invalid dataframe"
```

for case 2 we just need to check table

```
    finalresult2 = copy.deepcopy(result)
    for dic in finalresult2:
        if (isinstance(dic['table'],pyspark.sql.DataFrame)):
            dic[k] = "invalid dataframe"
```

in case this throws error you can find the correct class for the DataFrame using `type(x)`

Comment: Note that this answer does not assign the result to anything.

Comment: In the edited answers created deep copies to prevent altering the original dict.

Comment: Try running your code and show that it gives the right results by printing out the variables